# UINavigationBar question

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I added a UINavigationBar to my UIView

I am trying to set its title , and its leftbar byut it failed

I use the following code

```
self.title = @"Edit Table ";
UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Edit" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(EditTable:)];
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:addButton];
[super viewDidLoad];
```

nothing be changed , I call this uiview using

```
self.NodeSelection = [[NodesList alloc]initWithNibName:@"NodesList" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:self.NodeSelection animated:YES];
```

any suggestion please

Comment: How did you create the navigation item?

Comment: see my last comment in below answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

Call this View using

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.NodeSelection animated:YES];
```

You can change the title of NavigationBar using this

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"Hello";
```

and For leftBarButton your code is right.

**Second Update**

For return to parent screen

```
 [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: the problem is that the navigationbaritem , doesn't be updated

Comment: may I ask how to return back to the parent screen

Comment: @Marvin thanks alot , I have question regarding editing uitablview ,I know that when I click edit I can delete row , can I add another button, I mean when click  edit and select row ,I need a delete edit , buttons to appear do u have any suggestion

Comment: @AMH Please see this and download source code from there http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/iphone/examples/iphone-DeleteandaddrowfromTableView.html

Answer (score 0):

```
UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Edit" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(EditTable:)];
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:addButton];
[addButton release];
```